# JQuery filters row on click - Return function

Tags: jquery, filter, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

I have a small issue, look this collapsing tabble i have made

http://jsfiddle.net/hAv7P/12/

If you collapse the table you see "Fondos De Inversión" and "Sociedades".

I have applied a Jquery filter on click to the two span class "fondos" and "sociedades", so this is going to show the row which have the class "sr" and "dr". Untill here everything is fine

After that i want that if i click again on "sociedades" or "Fondos De Inversión" the functions shows again all the rows as in the beginning.

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/hAv7P/15/

is one of many ways to do it.
This uses the data feature of Jquery in order to track state.

You could just use 2 variables in the document ready scope.
like this
http://jsfiddle.net/hAv7P/16/

Comment: exactly, this is what i was looking for, i am now going to study your code examples...